# Java method is not invoked when calling it from native pthread

Tags: java, android, service, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need a simple Java service which starts at system boot and uses shared library with some functional which uses POSIX threads. While implementing JNI interface I faced with a some problem which doesn't allow me to make a Java method call from native code. GetMethodID() returns not NULL so I suppose it is doing well. Also there is no any suspicious errors which can help. So I added a lot of output to log and prepared a simple java test for that. (all the code is listed below, but project can be found in [this repository at github](https://github.com/YaMike/JavaServiceTest) as well).

List of the files of the project:

Service:

- TestService.java
- TestController.java
- TestListener.java
- **TestNative.java   <<-- java method is here**

Native code:

- **layer-jni.c       <<-- native call is here**

Other:

- Android.mk
- Application.mk
- AndroidManifest.xml

All files are listed below.

I tried the following logic in test service:

1.Service is started:

**TestService.java**:

```java
package com.example.testservice;

import java.lang.String;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestService extends Service {
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private TestController testCtrl = null;
    private static final String TAG = "TestService";

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
         public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
                       super(looper);
         }
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                 Log.e(TAG, msg.toString());
                 Log.e(TAG, "IT WORKS");
         }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Test has been stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
                           android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {         
        if (testCtrl != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service already running.");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting test controller");
        testCtrl = new TestController();
        Log.d(TAG, "Test controller has started");
    } 
}
```

2.It creates TestController class (where most of the logic must be) which creates TestNative class.

interface **TestListener.java**:

```java
package com.example.testservice;

public interface TestListener {
    public void stringJavaMethod(String regStr);
}
```

**TestController.java**:

```java
package com.example.testservice;

import android.util.Log;

public class TestController implements TestListener {
    private static final String TAG = "TestController";
    private TestNative mTestNative = null;

    TestController() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting test native");
        mTestNative = new TestNative(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void stringJavaMethod(String regStr) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Callback called!!!!\n");
        Log.e(TAG, regStr);
    }
```

}

**TestNative.java:**

```java
package com.example.testservice;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestNative implements TestListener {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("log");
        System.loadLibrary("layer-jni");
    }

    private static final String TAG = "TestNative";
    private Handler mHandler;
    private TestListener mDelegate;

    TestNative(TestListener t) {
        mDelegate = t;
        mHandler = new Handler();
        startAthread();
    }

    @Override
    public void stringJavaMethod(final String regStr) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IT WORKS?" + regStr);
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.e(TAG, "CALLED!\n");
                mDelegate.stringJavaMethod(regStr);
            }
        });
    }    

    /* native interface */
    public static native void startAthread();
}
```

3.TestNative class asks native library to start working via startAthread() method.
4.Native code stores JVM, makes a global reference for calling object and starts a thread.
5.Thread attaches himself to JVM and gets a new JNIEnv* pointer. Then it looks for Java method ID  using global object link which was obtained at step#4 and then it tries to call this method periodically.

The only native source is **layer-jni.c**:

```
#include "logcat.h"
#include "layer-jni.h"

#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>

JavaVM *jvm = NULL;
/* removed jObj UPD3 */
// jobject jObj;
/* added see UPD2 */
jclass jCls;
/******************/

static int run = 0;
static pthread_t t;
/* jobject -> jclass */
void callVoidMethodString(JNIEnv *env, jclass jcl, jmethodID jmid, const char *str);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *ajvm, void *dummy) {
        return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void *thread_func(void *dummy) {
        run = 1;
        JNIEnv *env = NULL;
        if (JNI_EDETACHED == (*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6)) {
                if ( 0 != (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, &env, NULL)) {
                        DBG_INFO("Cannot attach JNIEnv!\n");
                }
        }
        /* UPD2 - jObj -> jCls */
        jmethodID jmid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jCls, "stringJavaMethod", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        if (!jmid) {
                DBG_ERR("Cannot find java method...Terminating\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        while(run) {
                struct timespec ts = {.tv_sec = 1, .tv_nsec = 0 };
                nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
                DBG_INFO("Trying to call method\n");
                callVoidMethodString(env, jCls, jmid, "***** Native2Java call works! *****\n");
        }
        (*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
        return NULL;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_testservice_TestNative_startAthread( JNIEnv* env,
                jobject thiz)
{
        DBG_INFO("enter startAthread()\n");
        if (JNI_OK != (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &jvm)) {
                DBG_ERR("Cannot access Java VM! Terminating call.\n");
                return;
        }
        DBG_INFO("Caching class tc...\n");
        /* Updated: jObj replaced with jCls */
        jCls = thiz;
        jobject globalRef = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, jCls);
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jCls);
        jCls = globalRef;
        if (NULL == jCls) {
                DBG_ERR("Cannot cache class TronNative!\n");
                return;
        }
        /* UPD3: removed block below */
        /* Added see UPD2 */
        /*DBG_INFO("Caching class TestNative...\n");
         *jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/testservice/TestNative");
         *if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env) == JNI_TRUE){
         *   (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
         *   DBG_ERR("Exception while looking for TestNative class.\n");
         *   return;
         *}
         *jCls = (jclass)(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, clazz);
         *
         *if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env) == JNI_TRUE){
         *   (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
         *   DBG_ERR("Exception while trying to globalize TestNative class.\n");
         *   return;
         *}
         *(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, clazz);
         */
        /*****************/
        if (pthread_create(&t, NULL, thread_func, NULL)) {
                DBG_ERR("Cannot create thread!\n");
        }
}

static unsigned call_count = 0;

/* jobject -> jclass */
void callVoidMethodString(JNIEnv *env, jclass jcl, jmethodID jmid, const char *str) {
        jstring jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str);
        char calls_str[50] = {0};
        sprintf(calls_str, "calls:%u\n", call_count++);
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, jcl, jmid, jstr);
        if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
                DBG_ERR("There is some exceptional situation!\n");
                (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
                (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
        }
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jstr);
        DBG_INFO(calls_str);
}
```

6.As a result java method "public void stringJavaMethod(final String regStr)" is not invoked while CallVoidMethod() in native code is called. No any errors and no method call...

Log output I get while starting test service:

```
11-12 14:05:05.396: I/GAV2(18672): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
11-12 14:05:05.586: I/Autostart(16419): Starting service...
11-12 14:05:05.586: D/dalvikvm(18934): Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-12 14:05:05.586: I/ActivityManager(441): Start proc com.example.testservice for service com.example.testservice/.TestService: pid=18934 uid=10097 gids={50097, 3003, 1028}
11-12 14:05:05.606: D/dalvikvm(18934): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
11-12 14:05:05.696: D/dalvikvm(441): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1485K, 39% free 16961K/27776K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 89ms
11-12 14:05:05.736: I/TestService(18934): onCreate
11-12 14:05:05.736: D/TestService(18934): Starting test controller
11-12 14:05:05.736: D/TestController(18934): Starting test native
11-12 14:05:05.736: D/dalvikvm(18934): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/liblog.so 0x420e0a08, skipping init
11-12 14:05:05.736: D/dalvikvm(18934): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.testservice-1/liblayer-jni.so 0x420e0a08
11-12 14:05:05.736: D/dalvikvm(18934): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.testservice-1/liblayer-jni.so 0x420e0a08
11-12 14:05:05.736: I/JNITestService(18934): enter startAthread()
11-12 14:05:05.736: I/JNITestService(18934): Caching class tc...
11-12 14:05:05.736: D/TestService(18934): Test controller has started
11-12 14:05:06.736: I/JNITestService(18934): Trying to call method
11-12 14:05:06.736: I/JNITestService(18934): calls:0
11-12 14:05:07.736: I/JNITestService(18934): Trying to call method
11-12 14:05:07.736: I/JNITestService(18934): calls:1
...etc
```

Thus there are no any messages from Java code about call from native code and no java method invocation. And that's the problem. As a result I planned to see a string " Native2Java call works! \n" in the log which is passed as parameter to JNI call.

Listing of Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
ANDROID_NDK := /home/michael/Downloads/android-ndk-r8e
LOCAL_MODULE    :=         layer-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=         layer-jni.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
#APP_CPPFLAGS := -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -std=gnu++11
STLPORT_FORCE_REBUILD := true
APP_STL := stlport_shared
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service android:name=".TestService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.testservice.TestService">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name=".autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
                    android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I highly appreciate if somebody can help me with an advice or ideas what I have to check/to fix in my logic.

**UPD:** If I change Java method to static, GetMethodID() to GetStaticMethodID() and CallVoidMethod() to CallStaticVoidMethod() it starts working:

```
11-12 17:44:27.406: D/TestNative(21444): IT WORKS?***** Native2Java call works! *****
11-12 17:44:27.406: I/JNITestService(21444): calls:38
11-12 17:44:28.406: I/JNITestService(21444): Trying to call method
11-12 17:44:28.406: D/TestNative(21444): IT WORKS?***** Native2Java call works! *****
11-12 17:44:28.406: I/JNITestService(21444): calls:39
11-12 17:44:29.426: I/JNITestService(21444): Trying to call method
```

Still don't know the reason why non-static member is not working...

**UPD2:** Fixed call GetMethodID() - replace jObj with jCls. If jCls is obtained via FindClass() then result remains the same (no call, no error). If jCls is obtained via GetObjectClass() instead of FindClass() - then exception occured while trying to get method id using this new jCls:

```
11-12 18:17:59.926: D/TestService(22540): Test controller has started
11-12 18:17:59.926: E/JNITestService(22540): Cannot find java method...Terminating
11-12 18:17:59.926: W/dalvikvm(22540): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4198b700)
11-12 18:17:59.926: E/AndroidRuntime(22540): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6532
11-12 18:17:59.926: E/AndroidRuntime(22540): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='stringJavaMethod' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Ljava/lang/Class;
11-12 18:17:59.926: E/AndroidRuntime(22540):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

**UPD3**: Remove jObj, only jCls is used now. And parameter of startAthread has been fixed. But still no error, no call (non-static method, static version of method is working).

Comment: Its possible that the JNI on the static method lookup function is automatically converting the jobject to a jclass, but that is pure conjecture.

Comment: Make sure you have CheckJNI enabled; it can detect a number of minor issues.  See http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking

Comment: @fadden Valuable commentary, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jmethodID jmid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, jObj, "stringJavaMethod", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");`

This use of GetMethodID is incorrect.  The second parameter should be of type jclass, not jobject like you are using.

To convert the jobject to a jclass, use

`jclass GetObjectClass(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);`

Furthermore, you should be using `GetStaticMethodID` as your target method is static

**Edit 1**:

Checking the native method signature of `public static native void startAthread()` is incorrect.  It should be

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_startAthread(JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

Its currently

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_startAthread(JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

This difference explains why it works when you change the corresponding Java function to static, since you actually had a jclass object all along and not a jobject.

**Edit 2**

Now that the functions declarations are correct, the issue is clear: you are trying to call an instance-method without an instance of the class.  You will either need to change your static `startAthread` function to non-static and save the instance object, or you will need to change your called Java method to static.  Based on your actual implementation, choose the one that's right for you.

Comment: Thanks for response! I tried this approach and updated the topic. If I use GetObjectClass() I got exception. But strange - if I understand it correctly exception is about absence of method stringJavaMethod in class *java/lang/Object*! Am I right that jObj must be TestNative class instead of Object when coming into native code?

Comment: I double checked your native signature in your c++ code and its incorrect.  `public static native void startathread()` should generate a signature of `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_startAthread
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);`  So the object being passed to your native method is a jclass, you just have it typed wrong.  Sorry for the incorrect original answer. Updating

Comment: You're right. It's really must be a class. Updated according to this. This should be a habit to use javah.

Comment: Unfortunately if didn't help. Method is still not called.

Comment: @Michael OK, so lets think this through.  You have a class, `TestNative`, and you are calling a static method on that class( startAThread ).  But, within that native code, you want to call a non-static method on that class.  In order to do this, you will need that instance of TestNative passed into your native code.  Two options: Pass it as a reference to your static startAthread, or, change startAthread to non-static, and save your class' instance.  Make sense?

Comment: Thank you! Everything becomes clear to me. I need to be more attentive when reading documentation. I cant check it right now, but I'm sure it will be just fine tomorrow.